# How can i add tabs in google map info?

Tags: html, css, google-maps, tabs, openlayers

I want to add HTML tabs withdrawing current design of info window of google map. Something like this

[image]

I am going through OpenLayers API, but i am not sure how to achieve this.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use ***[Infobox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-basic.html)*** and create the HTML to make it look like your example using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs) + HTML.

I did this in my site and it worked great

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the programmer used to create that red Info Window in your screenshot.

However, **InfoBubble** is capable of creating tabs, and you can also customize its styles. Try the demos:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/